# failed to understand why ''Call to a member function send_notification() on null controllers/Admin.php 112"

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have got an error from online saver but in localhost does not appear.

The error from online saver is

```
Severity: error --> Exception: 
Call to a member function send_notification() on null controllers/Admin.php 112
```

I want to use this code to send messages to my customers.

This is a controller, Admin.php.

```
function notification($param1 = '', $param2 = '') 
{
    if ($param1 == 'create') 
    {
        $notification_code = $this->crud_model->create_notification();
        $check_notification_to_send = $this->input->post('check_notification');
        if ($check_notification_to_send == 1) {

            $data['title']     = $this->input->post('title');
            $customers  = $this->db->get('customer')->result_array();                
            $date           = date("d M,Y");
            $message  = $data['title'] . ' ';
            $message .= get_phrase('for more details please login to your  acc'). ' ';
            $message .= get_phrase('published on') . ' ' . $date;
            foreach($customers as $row) {
                $reciever_phone = $row['phone'];

                //This is the line 112 on which error originate
                $this->notification_model->send_notification($message , $reciever_phone);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the notification_model.

```
function send_notification($message = '' , $reciever_phone = '') {
    set_time_limit (0);

    require_once(APPPATH . 'libraries/twilio_library/Twilio.php');


    $accnt_sid    = $this->db->get_where('settings', array('type' => 'accnt_sid'))->row()->description;
    $auth_token     = $this->db->get_where('settings', array('type' => 'auth_token'))->row()->description;
    $client         = new Services_Twilio($accnt_sid, $auth_token); 

    $client->account->messages->create(array( 
        'To'        => $reciever_phone, 
        'From'      => $this->db->get_where('settings', array('type' => 'sender_phone_number'))->row()->description,
        'Body'      => $message   
    ));
}
```

This is the form in View directory

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <input required="" type="text" class="form-control" name="title">
</div>
<div class="form-group has-warning">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label"><i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i><?php echo get_phrase('send_sms');?></label>            
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <select required="" class="form-control" name="check_notification">
            <option value=""><?php echo get_phrase('select');?></option>
            <option value="1"><?php echo get_phrase('yes');?></option>
            <option value="2"><?php echo get_phrase('no');?></option>
        </select>
    </div>                
</div>
```

Comment: In your controller or in your function, you have not loaded the model `notification_model`.

Comment: what is notification_model() returning, check that method, I think thats where the problem is from

Comment: How can I load it? But in localhost everything is fine @Himanshu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to load your model in your controller using:

`$this->load->model('notification_model');` then you will be able to call the function in your controller.

Just make sure,
Declare your model function with `public`

so it will be like:

`public function send_notification($message = '' , $reciever_phone = '')`

Comment: Thanks, the previous problem solved but i have got another issue here it is "Exception: Class 'Services_Twilio_TinyHttp' not found"

Comment: ok @AbuuJurayj, as your original problem has been solved, can you please accept my answer?

Comment: i have accepted it but it says "vote cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded.....". But sorry we are together

Comment: Voting up is different, and accepting is totally different. You can always accept an answer to your question even with 1 reputation.